# What does this "imported in" maven-bundle-plugin OSGI warning mean?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

The Maven Apache Felix OSGI bundle plugin is emitting the following warning:

```
Bundle-Activator x.x.x is being imported into the bundle rather than being
    contained inside it. This is usually a bundle packaging error
```

What does this warning mean? My implementation of `BundleActivator` is specified with the `<Bundle-Activator>` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors tells you that it can find your specified Activator class in a package that is specified as imported package. The class is not packaged into your bundle though which is a quite unusual case.

I think the problem could be the Private-Package definition. You define the com.joyent.manta.cosbench.config.* as private. While the package with the Activator is not defined a private or exported.

If a package is not private or exported then it will be not included in the jar. Instead only an Import-Package statement is created. So you sohuld define the package with the Activator either as private or as exported. Then it should work.

Comment: The project is open-source and the OSGI configuration is here: https://github.com/joyent/cosbench-manta/blob/master/pom.xml#L165